# python Tkinter output is not display and a having a error

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, tkinter, tkinter-entry

#I Just perform some task taking a dictionary and the key of that dictionary is shown at the
#button text and after the press button, I give the command to show the value at the outbox
#value using class and object variable.
#but there is the problem I face it not show at the output..............

```
    from Tkinter import *
    
    list_word = []
    
    
    cell = []
    
    root = Tk()
    
    root.title("X1111Y22222Z")
    
    root.geometry('650x650')
    
    word_of_order={"123":"X1233YZ","124":"X1231YZ","125":"XY131Z","126":"X13Y123Z","127":"X13Y313Z","128":"X213Y131Z",
                   "129":"X13Y13Z","130":"X13Y131Z","131":"X1313Y113Z","132":"X123YZ","133":"X13Y131Z"}
                  # I want the dictionary value at the output section but
                  # cant fine it also I need to perform the destroy when a new entry is done
                  # can anyone solve this problem........
    
    class Elder:
    
        def __init__(self, master):
    
            myFrame = Frame(master)
    
            myFrame.pack()
    
            self.output = Text(myFrame)
    
            self.output.grid(row=0, column=2, columnspan=2)
    
            # Create text widget and specify size.
    
            e1_value = StringVar()
    
    
            self.Text = Entry(myFrame, textvariable=e1_value)
    
            self.Text = Text(root, height=1, width=20)
    
    
            self.Text.pack(side=LEFT)
    
            # Create Button
    
            self.myButton = Button(master, text="Search", command=self.open_login)
    
            self.myButton.pack(side=LEFT)
    
            self.scroll = Example(root)
    
            self. scroll.pack(side="right", fill="y")


                  # I want the dictionary value at the output section but
                  # cant fine it also I need to perform the destroy when a new entry is done
                  # can anyone solve this problem........
    
        def open_login(self):
    
            global cell
    
            global list_word
    
            for i in word_of_order.keys():
   
    
                b = Button(self.scroll, text=i, command=lambda : Example.train(i))
    
                b.pack(side=TOP)

                  # I want the dictionary value at the output section but
                  # cant fine it also I need to perform the destroy when a new entry is done
                  # can anyone solve this problem........
    
        def inner_search(self,Text):
    
            self. output.delete(1.0, END)


      #so anyone can help me....to rectify the code it is made with the help of class 
      #and object........
      # I want the dictionary value at the output section but
      # cant fine it also I need to perform the destroy when a new entry is done
      # can anyone solve this problem........
    
    class Example(Frame, Elder):
    
        def __init__(self, parent):
    
            Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    
            global cell
    
            self.text = Text(self, wrap="none")
    
            self.vsb = Scrollbar(orient="vertical", command=self.text.yview)
    
            self.text.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)
    
            self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
    
            self.text.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

                  # I want the dictionary value at the output section but
                  # cant fine it also I need to perform the destroy when a new entry is done
                  # can anyone solve this problem........
    
        def train(self):
    
            global cell
    
            for i in cell:
    
                self.btn = Button(text=i,command=lambda : Elder.inner_search(self,i))
    
                self.text.window_create("end", window=self.btn)
    
                self.text.insert("end", "\n")
    
    e = Elder(root)
    
    root.mainloop()
```

## I want the dictionary value at the output section but

## cant fine it also I need to perform the destroy when a new entry is done

## can anyone solve this problem........

Comment: Hello and welcome to [so]. Please format your code to have no indention errors and no unneccesary blank lines of code, better create a [mre] to higher your chances to get an answer. What makes me curios though, you have tagged your question with `python-3.x` but you use `from Tkinter import *`, while a uppercase T signals `python-2.x`. In addition please ask only one question at a time, to make your question usefull for others too. Please take a look at [ask].

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).